# use sensitive data in docker containers with docker compose

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a docker container that is running NGINX. Within the container I have an SSL cert that is currently being copied into the container. I would like to avoid using this approach and instead have the value of the SSL cert being passed in, so it is not stored on the container. In the docker-compose file, I have specified the public and private portions of the SSL certs as volumes and I have removed the commands from the Dockerfile that copies the values onto the image. However I am getting an error when running `docker-compose up` that the certificate cannot be loaded due to it not existing. Any advice on how I can accomplish this would be helpful. Thanks!

**Docker Compose**

```
version: "3"
services:
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    build: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./nginx/files/localhost.crt:/etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt
      - ./nginx/files/localhost.key:/etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    networks:
      - MyNetwork

networks:
  MyNetwork:
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx:latest
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
```

**Error**

```
[emerg] 1#1: cannot load certificate "/etc/nginx/nginx/files/localhost.crt": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/nginx/nginx/files/localhost.crt','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
```

Comment: I figured it out. I was passing in the wrong location.

Comment: ...since your configuration refers to `localhost.crt`, you need that as the second file name in the `volumes:` bind mounts.